# Active Directory Password Change Many pcs at once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, active-directory

I have been assigned to write a web application that will access active directory and change the password for multiple computers. The web app needs to be able to change like 80 computers passwords at once. Has anyone ever done anything like this? I am unsure of how to integrate active directory into a web application in order to do this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: *What has this question to do with javascript, jquery and html?*

Comment: those are the languages i will be using to make the web application. Just trying to see if anyone can lead me in the right direction

Comment: @DavidBierton Oh haha alright, I don't know much about AD with a web application, I was just wondering why the tags were there, good luck! :)

Comment: thank you i appreciate even checking out the question

Comment: you may refer this : https://github.com/gheeres/node-activedirectory or https://github.com/auth0/passport-windowsauth